# pymysql.internal Error (1403 , Bad Handshake)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pymysql

im trying to connect to my mysql Server. i wrote the Code on my Windows pc, and it worked…
now i tried to run the Code on my Raspberry and i get the traceback…

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host="ipoftheserver", port = 3306, user='user', passwd =' passwd')
```

Comment: Have you opened port 3306 for external connections? https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/mysql/how-to-grant-remote-access-mysql-vps

Comment: yes, but ist still not working